# Jquery - Function Not Defined Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a Function Not Defined Error when debugging my JQuery function. I'm sure there must be something small I'm missing here, but can't for the life of me see what it is.

Here's a Fiddle of the error:
https://jsfiddle.net/wnkby7nn/2/

The function declaration is as follows:

```
function formatDate(unformatteddate) {
    var date = new Date(unformatteddate);
    var formatteddate = (date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds());
    return formatteddate;
 }
```

And my function call is simply:

```
formatDate($('.startdate').text());
```

And the HTML in case that's useful too:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2009-04-29T16:55:09.0000000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You called the function `formatDate()` but you're trying to call it as `formatdate()`.  JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Where is the class `.startdate` defined?

Comment: Updated with the correct case and added in the startdate class - still not working though - https://jsfiddle.net/wnkby7nn/2/

Comment: There's no error reported when your jsFiddle runs.

Comment: It isnt showing any errors @LianeStevenson

Comment: Just seconding this, I'm not seeing any errors in Chrome's dev tools either...

Comment: Actually yep the error has gone - but the code still isn't working as it should

Comment: No errors from that jsFiddle in either Firefox or Chrome. Note that the code in the fiddle has no errors but it also doesn't *do* anything; the function is called but the return value is ignored.

Comment: @LianeStevenson That is because you are not setting it on the td.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a typo in the name of the function, which removed the error, and you forgot to re-assign the text to the div, which did not produce any result. Try this:

```
function formatDate(unformatteddate) {
    var date = new Date(unformatteddate);
    var formatteddate = (date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds());
    return formatteddate;
}

$('.startdate').text(formatDate($('.startdate').text()));
```

Updated JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1L30g2nj/1/

Comment: Damn it, 50 seconds too late.

Comment: Glad I could help! I added a link to a new JSFiddle to try it out. If this answer works, could you accept it so every one knows it's solved?

Comment: Just waiting for the timer to tick down :) - I'll accept when I can :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to display the formatted value inside the table cell that it's reading from. In that case, you should know jQuery's "text" function will either get or set the value; not both at once.

So this should be:

```
var target = $('td');
var formattedDate = formatDate(target.text());
target.text(formattedDate);
```